# AWS: Restrict API access to resources based on Cognito authentication role

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, microservices, amazon-cognito, service-discovery

I've set up a Microservices architecture in AWS for 3 deployment stages (DEV, STAGING, PROD).
I have two backends running. One is only intended for usage through mobile clients and the other backend supports web based access.

The backends are open for public access. Access is controlled through OAuth2 information provided by AWS Cognito. Authentication information contains several roles (ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_DEVELOPER, ROLE_ADMIN, ...).

Depending on the role I want to decide which hosts should be accessible by whom.

ROLE_CLIENT should only be able to see the PROD systems.
ROLE_DEVELOPER should be able to access the PROD & DEV systems.
ROLE_ADMIN is allowed to access any backend.

Example scenario: An user with role ROLE_CLIENT tries to access a DEV backend under *https://dev.myhost.com/path*. The response should be something like "403 Forbidden".

So far I came up with these ideas:

1. Implement a library which is shared across all backends. The library checks for the role on each access and throws an exception based on a hardcoded ROLE - STAGE mapping inside the library.
2. Define a central API Gateway somewhere which bundles all incoming traffic for all backend instances and uses Lambda to check if the role is allowed to call *https://[STAGE].myhost.com/path*.

Im not really happy with either of these solutions as both require some kind of hardcoded ROLE - STAGE mapping.

Is there any way to implement something like a service discovery for all backend host URLS? The next step would be to provide an API which clients can call to retrieve a list of possible URLs the can call based on their role.

Comment: Authorization is non-trivial and your question is pretty broad. If you are looking for unified policy-based access control look at [OPA](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/).  Pushing an access check to the client I would consider a bad practice as it is not really security.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Cognito groups to handle this? The typical scenerio would be:

1. Admin, dev and prod have their own groups. You assign various users the correct group. When user signs in their tokens will be generated based on their group. So they will have different role tokens
2. Once you have the token you can use API Gateway IAM authorizer and pass the token when making api calls.

I haven't used this method before but it should work.